# Finding and returning all prime numbers in an array. JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

If I get a random array, it does find all prime numbers, but when a number is not a prime number it will print a 0 instead just skipping that number.
Here's the a piece of code that I've written.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int el) {
    if (el > 1) {
        for (int i = 2; i < el; i++) {
            if (el % i == 0) {
            return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
public static int countPrimes(int[] seq) {
    int C = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < seq.length; n++) {
        if (isPrime(seq[n])) {
            C++;
        }
    }
    return C;
}
public static int[] primesIn(int[] seq) {
    int[] Array = new int [countPrimes(seq)];
    for (int i = 0; i < countPrimes(seq); i++) {
        if (isPrime(seq[i])) {
            Array[i] = seq [i];
        }
    }
    return Array;
}
```

And if I get the following array: new int[]{167, 173, 179, 191, 31, 89}.

It will return: [167, 173, 179, 0 ,191, 31].
I am not allowed to use lists and other things than a normal array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check all the input numbers, but output only the prime number to the array, you need 2 indices - one (`i`) that goes over the indices of the input array, and the other (`count`) that goes over the indices of the output array:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
    if (isPrime(seq[i])) {
        Array[count++] = seq[i];
    }
}
```

Test:

Input:

```
System.out.println (Arrays.toString (primesIn(new int[]{10, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20})));
```

Output:

```
[13, 17, 19]
```

Comment: @TomSaveur I get `{167, 173, 179, 191, 31, 89}` when the input is `{167, 173, 179, 191, 31, 89}`, and your original code also works for this input, since all the numbers are prime. Your code breaks when some of the input numbers are not prime.

Comment: sorry I found a small mistake in my own code, iyour solution now works!

Answer (score 0):

There is a performance issue here in the isPrime function. To find whether a number prime of not you don't need to ho till the number, you need to go till sqrt(n)

```
public static boolean isPrime(int el) {
if (el > 1) {
    int elsqrt= sqrt(el); // EDIT we don't want to do sqrt every time
    for (int i = 2; i < elsqrt; i++) {
        if (el % i == 0) {
        return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
 throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

This makes the program faster.

Comment: small correction. `sqrt(el)` is calculated on each step of the loop in your code.

Comment: Yes correct :) You don't want to do sqrt all the time. Added the fix